# Having issues with dice probability program

Tags: java, random

I am trying to make a program that calculates dice rolls using random digits and returns the probability of each sum happening for different numbers of rolls and trials. This code however only results in probabilities of zero displaying. This seems to be an issue with the establishment of the match variable in the nested for loop. Wondering what I am doing wrong. Is it establishing the match variable based on the counter?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DiceProbability
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randNumList = new Random();
    System.out.println("How many sides do the dice have: ");
    int diceSides = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many times will the dice be rolled: ");
    int diceRolls = in.nextInt();
    int highestSum = diceSides * 2;
    int diceRoll1 = 0;
    int diceRoll2 = 0;
    int match = 0;
    int totalOfDiceRolls = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    System.out.println("Rolls total   " + "Probability");
    for(counter=2;counter<=highestSum;counter ++)
  {
     for(counter2=1;counter2<=diceRolls;counter2 ++)
     {
     diceRoll1 = (randNumList.nextInt(11)+1);
     diceRoll2 = (randNumList.nextInt(11)+1);
     int totalOfRolls = diceRoll1 + diceRoll2;
     if(totalOfDiceRolls != counter)
        {
            match = match + 0;
        }
        else
        {
            match ++;
        }   
     }
     System.out.println(match);
     double probabilityOfSum = (match * 100 / diceRolls);
     System.out.println(counter + ":          " + probabilityOfSum);
     counter2 = 1;
    }
   } 
  }
```

Comment: This code is very confusing, but I'm fairly certain you don't mean `if (totalOfDiceRolls != counter)` since `totalOfDiceRolls` is initialized to 0 and never updated. That statement will always be true meaning `match` will always be 0.

Comment: Your code is not very explainatory, why do you take as an input the sides of a dice, and even in that case why do you draw rolls from 1-11? Having defined the dice sides and the number of rolls, you can calculate the propabilities of the sum using combinatoric formulas...counting combinations producing the sum over all combinations of the number of rolls.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly you are trying to calculate the relative frequency for each sum of two dices being rolled. If it's the case please edit your question as it's not that explicit in what your asking, especially that you have always two dices.

If you have two sided dices, your mathematical probability is as per below :

```
P(of having 2) = 1/4
P(of having 3) = 2/4
P(of having 4) = 1/4
```

All others are equal to 0.

[image]

Here is the code to achieve this. You need to save the frequency in an array and output correctly in dividing by the number of experiment.

Note: if you run this for a number less than 1000 this won't be accurate mathematically so it doesn't really make sense the user input the number of experiments in this case... ( in my opinion)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many sides do one dice have: ");
    int diceSides = in.nextInt();
    int[] results = new int[diceSides * 2 + 1];

        Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int resultdice1 =  rnd.nextInt(diceSides) + 1;
        int resultdice2 =  rnd.nextInt(diceSides) + 1;
        int sum = resultdice1 + resultdice2;

        results[sum] = results[sum] + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Probability to have sum of " + i + " is : " + (double) results[i] / 10000);

    }

}
```

Output :

[image]